# Zend: Using Row model method inside partialLoop

Tags: zend-framework, loops, model, partial-views

Zend talk.I have a view called "article" with a partialLoop inside,for displaying all comments in DB for that post:

```
[..]
echo $this->partialLoop('_comments.phtml',$this->comments);
```

this is _comments.phtml:

```
<li><?= $this->text." ".$this->datetime;?></li>
```

Since the structure of comments DB table is:

```
id(PK) | text | datetime | authorId
```

I wanted to retrieve the author name from "authors" DB table, with a CommentRow's method, from within _comments.phtml.

this is CommentRow model:

```
class CommentRow extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract
{
 function getAuthor()
 {
   $author=new Author();
   $q=$author->select('name');
   $q->where('id',$this->authorid);
   $result=$comment->fetchRow($q);
   return $result;  
 }
```

}

**How can I iterate through the array of comments(which are object of type CommentRow),passed to the partial loop,calling the getAuthor() method to display the comment's author name?**

thanks
Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Partial View Helper expects to you pass in a key/value structure. That can either be an associative array or an object. If you pass in an object any public properties will be considered unless the object has an `toArray` method returning an associative array with the desired keys and values. The keys and values passed to the helper will be made available in the partial. That means your `Zend_Db_Rowset` no longer exists in the partial. Read below how to pass it properly.

Quoting the [Reference Guide for the Partial View Helper](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html):

> If your model is an object, you may want to have it passed as an object to the partial script, instead of serializing it to an array of variables. You can do this by setting the 'objectKey' property of the appropriate helper:
>
> ```
> // Tell partial to pass objects as 'model' variable
>   $view->partial()->setObjectKey('model');
>
> // Tell partial to pass objects from partialLoop as 'model' variable
>   // in final partial view script:
>   $view->partialLoop()->setObjectKey('model');
> ```
>
> This technique is particularly useful when passing `Zend_Db_Table_Rowsets` to `partialLoop()`, as you then have full access to your row objects within the view scripts, allowing you to call methods on them (such as retrieving values from parent or dependent rows).

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($this->comments as $comment) {
 echo $comment->getAuthor()->nickname;  // output nickname column of author for example
}
```

See [Zend_Db_Table_Rowset](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.rowset.html) for more detailed examples.

Comment: I dont think I understand=S Im wanting to use the getAuthor() method inside the partial Loop